# Error building AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I'm trying to build `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` but I'm getting the following errors:

`.NETStandard,Version=v1.3 error NU1002: The dependency System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.0.0-rc3-23911 in project AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server does not support framework .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.`

If I remove the reference to `netstandard1.3` in `projects.json` the project builds without errors.

I'm using the latest unstable DNX (`1.0.0-rc2-16595`) on Windows.

Can anyone help me figure out what's happening?

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: More info: I can run the project without errors if I do it from the command line with `dnx web`. However, if I try to build it from inside Visual Studio, I get the aforementioned error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is likely caused by the fact some of the CoreFX Crypto packages were recently updated to require `netstandard1.4` instead of `dotnet5.4`/`netstandard1.3`:

4.0.0-rc3-23911:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/01/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.4">
    <id>System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl</id>
    <version>4.0.0-rc3-23911</version>
    <title>System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl</title>
    <authors>Microsoft</authors>
    <owners>microsoft,dotnetframework</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=329770</licenseUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=288859</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Provides cryptographic algorithm implementations and key management for non-Windows systems with OpenSSL.

Commonly Used Types:
System.Security.Cryptography.RSAOpenSsl
 \r\n TFS ID: 1583883, GitHub SHA: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/3cabb976e023a5fb43143f47cfbceca60c0268a5</description>
    <copyright>© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.4">
        <dependency id="runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography" version="[4.0.0-rc3-23911, )" />
        <dependency id="System.Collections" version="[4.0.11-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
        <dependency id="System.IO" version="[4.0.11-rc3-23911, )" />
        <dependency id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="[4.0.1-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime" version="[4.0.21-rc3-23911, )" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="[4.0.11-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="[4.0.1-rc3-23911, )" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="[4.0.21-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="[4.0.1-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
        <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="[4.1.0-rc3-23911, )" />
        <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="[4.0.0-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
        <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="[4.0.0-rc3-23911, )" />
        <dependency id="System.Text.Encoding" version="[4.0.11-rc3-23911, )" exclude="Compile" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

4.0.0-rc2-23826:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/01/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.4">
    <id>System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl</id>
    <version>4.0.0-rc2-23826</version>
    <title>System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl</title>
    <authors>Microsoft</authors>
    <owners>microsoft,dotnetframework</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=329770</licenseUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=288859</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Provides cryptographic algorithm implementations and key management for non-Windows systems with OpenSSL.

Commonly Used Types:
System.Security.Cryptography.RSAOpenSsl
 \r\n TFS ID: 1579044, GitHub SHA: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/dacca1618c0dbb266945d42e58b9584e7c72126c</description>
    <copyright>© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETPlatform5.4">
        <dependency id="runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography" version="4.0.0-rc2-23826" />
        <dependency id="System.Collections" version="4.0.0" />
        <dependency id="System.IO" version="4.0.10" />
        <dependency id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime" version="4.0.20" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.0.10" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.0.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.0.20" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.0.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.0.0-rc2-23826" />
        <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.0.0-rc2-23826" />
        <dependency id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.0.0-rc2-23826" />
        <dependency id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.0.10" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework="MonoAndroid1.0" />
      <group targetFramework="MonoTouch1.0" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETCore5.0" />
      <group targetFramework="Xamarin.iOS1.0" />
      <group targetFramework="Xamarin.Mac2.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

This doesn't impact our builds because we only use the `aspnetcidev` feed (that doesn't have the CoreFX RC3 packages yet), but you probably downloaded a project using the `dotnet-core` feed recently, which caused the RC3 package to be persisted in your global packages store (`.nuget\packages`).

To temporarily work around this issue, you can re-target ASOS to use `netstandard1.4` or wipe your `.nuget\packages` folder and use the RC2 packages.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I cleared the package store and changed `project.json` to use `netstandard1.4` and now all dependencies are resolved successfully.  However, when I try to build the solution I get the following error:  `CS1061: 'X509Store' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'X509Store' could be found`  on line 152 of `OpenIdConnectServerHelpers.cs`.  I'm wondering if it's really required to tell the `X509Store` to `Close()` after use.  In any case, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you also rename the NETSTANDARD1_3 symbol to NETSTANDARD1_4?

Comment: Renaming `NETSTANDARD1_3` to `NETSTANDARD1_4` did the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: Nice! Glad you sorted it out! ;)

Comment: Hello @Pinpoint, last night I updated my copy of `ASOS` from GitHub and I'm trying to figure out what's happening, maybe you can help me?

I made the aforementioned changes and I'm able to run the project without any problems when I do from the command line via `dnx web`.

However, I cannot build it from inside VS2015. I get several CS1705 errors. I thought VS used the same path for tools and compiler as `dnx`, but apparently that's not the case. Can you help me or point me in the right direction?

Once again, thanks so much for you help. Regards, Pedro.

Comment: Hey. The last 2 weeks were absolutely terrible as even the CI server wasn't able to build the aspnet-contrib projects but everything was addressed yesterday: you should be able to build ASOS with both DNX and CLI and use VS without seeing weird messages. If it still doesn't work, try clearing your packages (`C:\Users\[profile]\.nuget\packages`). FYI, I'll update ASOS to target `netstandard1.4` soon (probably today or tomorrow).

Comment: FYI, the aspnetcidev feed is being updated ATM. You should wait until all the packages are online. I'll push the `netstandard1.3` -> `netstandard1.4` change when it's done.

Comment: I'm also seeing weird issues with the latest packages. Sadly, there's nothing I can do :(

Comment: Pinpoint, thanks for your help anyway - at least I know I'm not doing anything wrong! FYI, I'm still able to build and run ASOS with `dnx web` but no success with VS.

Comment: You can find more info about this "bug" on this topic: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/76#issuecomment-201058572.

Comment: Thanks! That explains the error messages I've been getting in VS2015, but I still don't understand why it builds and runs without problems with `dnx web`. I'll keep researching. Once again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @pealmeid the IdentityModel packages have been rebuilt. Building ASOS should now work fine with both DNX and CLI.

Comment: Building is working as expected, thanks a lot for your help!